# How to create .app with relative path to .dylib?

Tags: macos, cmake

currently using target_link_libraries I link with some libraries, including qt, glew and assimp 3.0

in cmake I'm calling find (which calls assimp-config) and then use returned `ASSIMP_LIBRARIES` variable and pass it to target_link_libraries and everything is fine except path to assimp dylib inside my .app is absolute when all other paths are relative to @executable and point into `.app/Content/Frameworks/` folder so I can destribute my app.

so far I can't see where is difference that I need between glew (for example) and assimp but when I check dependies with `otool -L` I can see that whatever I do assimp is linking with absolute path and my application can't find this dylib inside `Frameworks`

how to ensure that linking path of my application with that library will be relative in app bundle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `POST_BUILD` custom command to fix the dependent shared library install name with the `install_name_tool` command line tool, e.g.:

```
add_custom_command (TARGET myAppExecutable
    POST_BUILD COMMAND "${CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL}"
        "-change" "/usr/local/lib/libassimp.dylib" "@executable_path/../Frameworks/libassimp.dylib"
    "$<TARGET_FILE:myAppExecutable>" VERBATIM)
```